# Send a bubble into a teams meeting through bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, officedev

After downloading and running the sample project ([Meeting Token Generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-meetings-token)) I tried to create my own bot. So I followed the steps  2 and 3 (in the previous link) to create a new resource and a new bot channel registration. After this I replicated the method **[PostStatusChangeNotification](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-meetings-token/blob/b9643bd630ef2ccc7eca0db525934e39082c72f9/Service/MeetingService.cs)** (from visual studio project), that should sends a bubble, into a java function, on a springboot project.
So I used **continueConversation** method from **BotFrameworkHttpAdapter** to send the bubble.

There are these two problems:

1. As the docs (of method continueConversation): *Most channels require a user to initiate a conversation with a bot before the bot can send activities to the user*. So, how meeting token generator can send activities into a meeting chat **without user conversation init**?
2. Why bubble not showing when my bot send the activity? Only chat message works. I also tried to manually post (with postman) the same JSON payload generated by Meeting Token Generator (modifying the data to be modified), and I noticed that the bubble is shown **only** using Meeting Token Generator's bot.
   So the same post request with a different bot's bearer token doesn't show the bubble, but only in-chat message. I really can’t explain it.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Can we discuss this over a call? Could you please write to us at microsofteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks for response @Manish-MSFT , I tried to send an email but microsofteamsdev was not found on microsoft.com :/

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, Please try to send it to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.